# how to get array of databases in localhost using PDO

Tags: php, mysql

trying to get an array of databases in localhost using PDO

```
$user = 'root';
$server = 'localhost';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$server", $user);

$sql = "show databases";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$arr = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($arr as $el){
    echo $el . '<br>'; // error - array to string conversion
}
```

also tried:

```
 $arr = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

result - only the first database is echoed

Any help?

Comment: You can use `var_dump($el);` to see what was returned from the statement - since you're asking for `FETCH_ASSOC`, an associative array will be returned with a key for each value you're looking for.

Comment: just replace `echo $el . '<br>';` => `print_r($el) . '<br>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Information from the information schema like:

```
SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`;
```

There are also more infos about the databases (schemas)

**sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`;
+--------------------+
| SCHEMA_NAME        |
+--------------------+
| bernd              |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: and how to get the array from the above query?

Comment: If this is a query in PHP PDO, you can use `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the result and print it:

```
while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($arr);
}
```

The result is going the name of databases in your localhost. For example:

```
Array
(
    [Database] => mysql
)
Array
(
    [Database] => performance_schema
)
Array
(
    [Database] => phpmyadmin
)
```

Edit:

```
$databases = [];
while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $databases[] = $arr["Database"];
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need the array as a variable for other functions

Comment: What do you mean array as a variable? like each row will print the name of the database as a string variable and not an array?

Comment: like this - $arr = ['firstdb', 'seconddb'...]

Comment: it works now, thanks. Just a note - I have now two loops - `while` for getting array and `foreach` for echoing. I hope there is a way to have only one of them.

Comment: Remove your foreach loop

Comment: They both do the same thing